# あめ が ちょうど ていしして

Tags: grammar

Is it natural to say the meaning of  “while the rain just stopped, it rains again now” in Japanese as below?

あめ が ちょうど ていしして、いま は ふたたび ふりましています。

Comment: 停止{ていし} means to stop moves or stop something in ongoing operation. So 停止 doesnt fit this sentence.

Answer (score 4):

First, for rain you should use 止む｛やむ｝ instead of 停止｛ていし｝。
Also, I would use ばかり instead of ちょうど.
ふりましています is probably just a mistake, you should write ふっています.

I would say something like

> 雨｛あめ｝が止んだ｛やんだ｝ばっかりなのに、再び｛ふたたび｝降り｛ふり｝始めました｛はじめました｝。

Comment: wouldn't ふりだす be more appropriate than ふりはじまる?

Comment: @A.Ellett どちらでもいいかと・・・ Both sound natural to me...（「ふりはじ**め**る」ですけどね）「降り出した」のほうが口語的かも

Comment: How about ”降ってきた” though? 雨が止んだばっかりなのに、また降ってきた

Comment: @DanMa it's just yet another way to say it.